# Slide image with swipe handler in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have created some images in Adobe PhotoShop to introduce the user to an application in WP 8.1 in C#. I want to display and intro Page, only if the user's settings is empty (it is a very simply but good boolean condition for my case).

So when the user open for the first time the application, the first image will be opened, if the user swipe to the left, the second one will appear, in case swipe to the right, nothing should happen, because the image -1 doesn't exist:

```
public int getPage (int newPage)
{
    if (0 <= newPage <= N_IMAGES) {
        return newPage;
    }
    if (newPage < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return N_IMAGES;
    }
}
```

My images are named: intro1.png, intro2.png, intro3.png and intro4.png. 
So to summary it: Open application, first intro, swipe left, second intro....

1. How Can I make this intro in WP 8.1 ? 
   So the intro is like a slide show, where the images changed on swipe left/right.
2. For the last images, is possible to add over it, some button, not displayed, but clickable ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

UPDATE x2 (WORKS)

Hi,
I finally let it works; the problem was due to the fact that the images, must be added in a particular way, and not just copy and past.

```
<Grid Name="introgrid">
    <FlipView x:Name="flipView1" SelectionChanged="FlipView_SelectionChanged">

        <FlipViewItem Name="first" Width="395">
            <FlipViewItem.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/intro1.png"/>
            </FlipViewItem.Background>

        </FlipViewItem>
        <FlipViewItem Name="second" Width="395">
            <FlipViewItem.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/intro2.png"/>
            </FlipViewItem.Background>
        </FlipViewItem>

        <FlipViewItem Name="third">
            <FlipViewItem.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/intro3.png"/>
            </FlipViewItem.Background>
        </FlipViewItem>
        <FlipViewItem Name="final" Width="395">
            <FlipViewItem.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/3.jpg"/>
            </FlipViewItem.Background>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Image Source="Assets/Face.png" Width="180" />
                <TextBlock Text="Se hai già le credenziali:" FontSize="25" Margin="0,15,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button x:Name="login" Content="Accedi" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,15,0,0" FontSize="22" Background="#FF0DACE9" Click="login_action" />
                <TextBlock Text="Se non ti sei ancora registrato:" FontSize="25" Margin="0,15,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button x:Name="register" Content="Registrati" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,15,0,0" FontSize="22" Background="#FF0DACE9" Click="register_action" />
                <TextBlock Text="Hai qualche domanda ?" FontSize="25" Margin="0,15,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button x:Name="info" Content="Sito web" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,15,0,0" FontSize="22" Background="#FF0DACE9" Foreground="White" Click="info_action" />
            </StackPanel>




        </FlipViewItem>
    </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you format somehow your question?

Comment: I just want an intro for the users, who open for the first  time the application . It will be like the Dropbox one, but I have already created the images in PhotoShop, so it will be something like a slide show.

Comment: I've asked only if you could edit your question so that it would be more readable. As for the answer - loose thinking - I would try to put some images off the screen and use animation to swipe them to visible part of the screen.

Comment: That's what I want ! Sorry if the question isn't so readable, I tried to be as clear as I can !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FlipView control is probably what you need.

You can have a setting in the app local storage that will tell you when this view has been displayed and on next load not show it if the setting exists.

More info on FlipView
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781233.aspx

Comment: That's a good solution ! Do you think is possible add some buttons over a background, just clickable ?

Comment: Sure, you can use the FlipView.ItemTemplate for this.

Comment: Thank you. I have update the question, it works but I can't see the images.

Comment: Why are the images inside a StackPanel?

Comment: Hi, I edit the post. Right now it works quite well. The only problem is that I can't launch this intro page, from the Main page in the costructucr. What do you think could be problem ?

Comment: Try doing it in the page loaded event instead.

Comment: Yes, you're right ! Just a few minutes ago I tried and works everything correctly ! Thank you for your support !